# Rails - Group_by method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to group items (games) by month in rails and SQL3 but it generates this :

**Error**

**March 17th**

```
<% @game_months.each do |month, games| %>
    <% for game in games %>
    <a href="<%= game_path(game)%>" class="col-md-4 m-t-md">
   <div class="box b-a m-a" style="box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);">
```

**Here is my games controller**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController



def index
    @game = current_user.games
    @games = Game.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @game_months = @games.group_by {|g| g.created_at.beginning_of_month }
end
```

**My view**

```
<% @game_months.each do |month, games| %>
        <% for game in games %>
        <a href="<%= game_path(game)%>" class="col-md-4 m-t-md">
    <div class="box b-a m-a" style="box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);">
      <div class="item b-b">
                <div><%= image_tag game.photos[0].image.url(:medium), class:"img-responsive" if game.photos.length > 0 %></div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-a text-left white">
        <h6 class="text-md text-black block p-b-sm"><strong><%= game.game_name %></strong></h6>
        <span class="text-muted p-t-md"><%= game.game_description %></span>
        <div class="m-t-md">
                <span><%= image_tag avatar_url(game.user), class:"w-24 circle b-a" %></span>
        <span class="m-t-sm text-black pull-right text-md"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know what i'm doing bad. Please help, i don't know what to do to solve this!

CHEERS! :)

Comment: So what is the error showing in the log? what do you mean by `Group_by method doesn't work`?

Comment: You want to group by months OR month + year combination? e.g. If there are entries for Jan 2017, and Jan 2018, you want them together or in separate arrays?

Comment: hey, i just want to group and show items like that: month1 (item1, item2...) , month2 (item1, item2...) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@games = Game.all.order("created_at DESC")
@game_months = @games.group_by {|g| g.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

To

```
@game_months = Game.all.group_by { |g| g.created_at.month }
```

It should produce hash looking like this:

```
{1=>[GameObject1], 2=>[GameObject3, GameObject4], 3=>[GameObject2] ...}
```

Now iterate over **hash** and do what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry but Doesn't work error --> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #64):

Comment: Could you stop posting HTML? Also edit your question and place your comment content there.